# Button in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my request: I want to create a list of elements, composed of 2 textblock and 1 button (the structure is defined with ResourceDictionary). Each value in the list is a variable of an ObservableCollection property. My problem is in the management of the button, I would like to make sure that when it is clicked the corresponding variable in the property is eliminated. What is the best approach to achieve this? I have implemented a ListBox but I don't know how to handle the button with the mvvm pattern. (Excuse my English and thanks)

Comment: `What is the best approach to achieve this?, I have implemented a ListBox but I don't know how to handle the button with the mvvm pattern`, please show us your approach, what isn't working and expected output so we can better assist you and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you!.

This is my example:
[this is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU59V.jpg)

My code for ResourceDictionary:

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CountryTemplate">
    <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5" Margin="5" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=name}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=nation}" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="B_Delete" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonRed}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Text="X"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

My code for the view xaml:

```
<ListBox Margin="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AddCountry}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryTemplate}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

I implemented a solution with ButtonBase.Click but is not correct for the mvvm pattern, I wrote a class for ICommand with name RelayCommand.

Answer (score 0):

OK!!

You can take advantage of the Command and the CommandParameter and figure out which clicked item in the method that handles the click...

**Here is in more detail:**

First, the RelayCommand that accepts parameters:

```
 public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then, in your view model, you'll instantiate a ICommand with that RelayCommand:

```
  public ICommand ClickMeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_clickMeCommand == null)
                _clickMeCommand = new RelayCommand<SomeItem>(DoSomething);
            return _clickMeCommand;
        }
    }


     private void DoSomething(SomeItem obj)
    {
        //Note that here you can manipulate the "obj" any way you want.
        //This "obj" is excacly that one was clicked

        obj.ClickCount++;
        ClickedText = $"ID: [{obj.AnimalId}] - Animal: [{obj.AnimalName}] {Environment.NewLine} ClickCount:[{obj.ClickCount}]";
    }
```

And in the View side:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Azure">
                    <StackPanel Margin="20,3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,2,10,0" Text="Click  &gt;&gt;  " />
                        <Button
                            Width="90"
                            Height="25"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickMeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Content="{Binding AnimalName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

> In your case, the definition of elements is in a dictionary, so, you better take care if you're reusing this in another place, if yes, and it is a expected situation, so you have to have the ICommand inplementation in that ViewModel. If no, maybe you should take it of from the dictionary or define it on a limited scope...
>
> Note that the CommandParameter is being set just with a "{Binding}"  which is the current item of that ListBox that comes from the ItemSource which is your ObservableCollection.
>
> If you change something in that object it'll change automatically wherever it is being used, since it is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Here is the code for this concept:
https://github.com/mateusavelar/RelayCommand-Implementation

Take Care!!